# How to correctly override literal operators?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, string-literals

Ok, so I made my own class and I've overloaded an operator `""s` so I can use it for my string formation.

BUT, I get an error when compiling and I have no idea what it means.
Could someone explain the meaning of it and how to fix it?

my code:

```
PString operator"" s(const char* text, std::size_t len) {
    return PString(std::string(text, len));
}
```

my error:

```
error: ‘PString PString::operator""s(const char*, std::size_t)’ must be a non-member function
 PString operator"" s(const char* text, std::size_t len) {
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message actually? It seems you try to override the literal operator as part of a class.

Comment: What I'm unclear about is this part of the error message `must be a non-member function` as I don't know what it means - what is this so-called `non-member`

Comment: It means you must create a free function outside the `PString` class.

Comment: free function? What do you mean by that? A function named `free` or something else?

Comment: No a function outside of any class declaration like `std::min()` or such.

Comment: I don't quite understand... what would `std::min()` do for me in this case? It's not used anywhere.

Comment: I didn't say it should do something for you, you should just make your operator overload outside of the class or make it a `friend` function. And no, I'm not going to chat with you about that. Read a book to get the basic terminology.

Comment: I think I understand now... I need to overload operator outside of the class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what the compiler means with _`non member function`_.

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear now!

Comment: Read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @JiveDadson I've already read that. What's wrong with my question? I can't see the problem. Title? Contents? Please tell me, so I can fix my problems next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so prior to asking this question I've been confused about something. Because I've added other operator overrides inside of the class, I thought that I was supposed to add that `operator"" s` inside of the class as well. But apparently, that is not so.

I'm keeping this just as a reference to the answer @user0042 gave to me.

This is what solved the problem for me.